# CMSIS-RTOSv2 - Access out of bounds in RTX RTOS window

Tags: arm, keil, cmsis, rtx-rtos

During migrating my project to RTOSv2 and RTXv5, I recognize that after a few minutes my program hangs and the messages appear at the RTX RTOS window:

```
Expression: 'QML[j + QCB[i].ml_idx].addr'
E303: Access out of bounds - <readlist 'QML[44]'> - actual index:=45
```

I find the source of the hard fault is the "**memcpy**" function.

CMSIS_5/CMSIS/RTOS2/RTX/Source/rtx_msgqueue.c

```
/// Put a Message into a Queue or timeout if Queue is full.
osStatus_t osMessageQueuePut (osMessageQueueId_t mq_id, const void *msg_ptr, uint8_t msg_prio, uint32_t timeout) {
  EvrRtxMessageQueuePut(mq_id, msg_ptr, msg_prio, timeout);
  if (IS_IRQ_MODE() || IS_IRQ_MASKED()) {
    return isrRtxMessageQueuePut(mq_id, msg_ptr, msg_prio, timeout);
  } else {
    return  __svcMessageQueuePut(mq_id, msg_ptr, msg_prio, timeout);
  }
}
...
/// Put a Message into a Queue or timeout if Queue is full.
/// \note API identical to osMessageQueuePut
__STATIC_INLINE
osStatus_t isrRtxMessageQueuePut (osMessageQueueId_t mq_id, const void *msg_ptr, uint8_t msg_prio, uint32_t timeout) {
  os_message_queue_t *mq = (os_message_queue_t *)mq_id;
  os_message_t       *msg;
  const void        **ptr;
  ...
  // Try to allocate memory
  msg = osRtxMemoryPoolAlloc(&mq->mp_info);
  if (msg != NULL) {
    // Copy Message
    memcpy((uint8_t *)msg + sizeof(os_message_t), msg_ptr, mq->msg_size);
    ...
  return osOK;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas for this problem?
Thanks,...

Bacheh Karaji

Comment: "I find the source of the hard fault is the "memcpy" function." - I strongly doubt that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I select the Source variant of the software component CMSIS:RTOS2 (API):Keil RTX5, from the Manage Run-Time Environment dialog. **Everything Is Fine!**